# Calling a Scheme function using its name from a list

Tags: function, scheme, evaluation, invocation

Is it possible to call a Scheme function using only the function name that is available say as a string in a list?

#### Example

```
(define (somefunc x y)
  (+ (* 2 (expt x 2)) (* 3 y) 1))

(define func-names (list "somefunc"))
```

And then call the somefunc with `(car func-names)`.

Answer (score 14):

In many Scheme implementations, you can use the `eval` function:

```
((eval (string->symbol (car func-names))) arg1 arg2 ...)
```

You generally don't really want to do that, however.  If possible, put the functions themselves into the list and call them:

```
(define funcs (list somefunc ...))
;; Then:
((car funcs) arg1 arg2 ...)
```

#### Addendum

As the commenters have pointed out, if you actually want to map strings to functions, you need to do that manually.  Since a function is an object like any other, you can simply build a dictionary for this purpose, such as an association list or a hash table.  For example:

```
(define (f1 x y)
  (+ (* 2 (expt x 2)) (* 3 y) 1))
(define (f2 x y)
  (+ (* x y) 1))

(define named-functions
  (list (cons "one"   f1)
        (cons "two"   f2)
        (cons "three" (lambda (x y) (/ (f1 x y) (f2 x y))))
        (cons "plus"  +)))

(define (name->function name)
  (let ((p (assoc name named-functions)))
    (if p
        (cdr p)
        (error "Function not found"))))

;; Use it like this:
((name->function "three") 4 5)
```

Comment: I think a lot of people come from Ruby and similar backgrounds and expect to be able to use name-based dispatch (e.g., Ruby's `Kernel#send` method). In Scheme, there is no direct mechanism for name-based dispatch, and people need to design programs with that in mind, e.g., building a hash table with the name-to-function associations.

Comment: That's true, but a more complete answer would show how to write a macro that creates functions and the mapping table.